# Can't Escape Limit Value in Mysql & Express Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sql-limit

I'm developing an API with Node.js (+Express JS) and MySQL. I can't escape or add custom limit value to my query. Here is my route;

```
app.post('/api/v1/fetch/limitedArticles/:limit', (req, res,) => {

    const limitValue = req.params.limit;

    let query = "SELECT article_id, article_name, article_image, article_url FROM ?? ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT ?";

    mysqlDB.query(query, ['app_articles', limitValue], function (mysqlError, mysqlRes) {
        if(mysqlError){
            return res.status(500).send({message: "error_server_db"});
        }else if(mysqlRes.length<1){
            return res.status(404).send({message: "warning_empty_list"});
        }else{
            //All good
            return res.status(200).send(mysqlRes);
        }
        throw mysqlError;

    })
});
```

**I request as;**

```
{{api_base_url}}/api/v1/fetch/limitedArticles/2
```

And I get this error;

```
{
"message": {
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT article_id, article_name, article_image, article_url FROM `app_articles` ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT '2'"
}
```

}

If I remove parameter value and type "2" to my limit value (e.g LIMIT 2), it works. But it doesn't work as I showed.

Comment: LIMIT argument must be numeric parameter LITERALLY. So wrapping quotes are treated as its part - with according error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=11f0fad6d6daa1c40466abe20cf897f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limitValue` is a string - you should convert it to a number so it can be used in the `limit` clause:

```js
const limitValue = Number(req.params.limit);
```